# Number theoretic problem - Representation of even number as difference of two numbers that are coprime to it.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Someone gave me this problem:

> Show that every even number $n$ is the difference of two natural numbers $a,b$ both of which are coprime to a given number $c$.

I have trouble to use the somehow make the information that $a$ and $b$ are coprime to $c$ useful. Any hints for this are appreciated. Thanks in advance I usually come up with something but this time I have no clue. I know we can write
$$
\frac{a+b}{2}=m
$$
where $n=2m$ but this does not help either. I also constructed a few examples but I found no real pattern.

Comment: You seek an integer $\,x = \,a\,$ such that $\,x\,$ and $\,x+n\,$ are coprime to $\,c,\,$  which [is equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3555162/242) to their product $\,f(x)= x(x+n)\,$ being coprime to $\,c.\,$ CRT allows us to easily tackle such problems for any polynomial $f(x)$ with integer coef's - see my comment on Calvin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $c>1$ (otherwise the answer is obvious). The problem is equivalent to: find two elements of $\Bbb Z_c^\times$ (the set of invertible elements of $\Bbb Z_c$) which differ by $n\bmod c.$

By the Chinese remainder theorem, we may restrict to the case where $c$ is a power of some prime $p.$

If $p\ne2$ then $\varphi(c)>c/2$ so the injective map $\Bbb Z_c\to\Bbb Z_c,\;t\mapsto t+(n\bmod c)$ cannot send every invertible to a non-invertible, and we are done.

If $p=2,$ the set of differences of two elements of $\Bbb Z_c^\times$ is $2\Bbb Z_c.$ It contains $n\bmod c$ since $n$ is even, so again we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P$ be the set of primes such that $1 + n \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$.
Let $Q$ be the set of primes such that $ -1 + n \not \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$.

Claim: Prove that $P \cup Q$ is the set of all primes.
(I'm not requiring that it's a disjoint union.)

Consider the prime decomposition of $c = \prod p_i^{r_i}$.
Solve the modular arithmetic system
$a \equiv  \begin{cases} 1 \pmod{p_i}  & p_i \in P \\ -1 \pmod{p_i} & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

Claim: Prove that $a, b=a+n$ satisfy the conditions of the problem.

Followup: Where did we use that $n$ is even?
Can we modify the proof so that this works for all numbers $n$?

Comment: More generally, to show $\,f(x) = x(x+n)\,$ has a value coprime to $\,c = \prod p_i^{e_i}$ it suffices to show for every $\,i\,$ that $f\,$ has a value coprime to  $p_i,\,$ i.e. $\,f(x_i)\not\equiv 0\pmod{\!p_i},\,$ since then we get a solution by using CRT to solve the system $\,x\equiv x_i\pmod{\!p_i}.\,$ It's clear if $\,p_i > 2 = \deg f\,$ since $\Bbb Z_p$ is a field so $f$ has as most $2 < p_i$ roots, so there is a nonroot $\,x_i.\,$ If some $\,p_i = 2\,$ then $\bmod 2\!:\ n\equiv 0\Rightarrow f = x(x+n)\equiv x^2\,$ so $\,f(1)\not\equiv 0$.

Comment: The same idea works for higher degree polynomials $\,f\in\Bbb Z[x]\,$ (that don't vanish mod any $p_i,$ i.e. $p_i$ does not divide some coef). As above, we reduce to finding a nonroot for all primes $p_i \le \deg f)$.