# If a number $n$ shares a common factor with $p^{\alpha}$, then $p|n$.

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

Let $p$ be prime, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$. Suppose that $n$ shares a common factor with $p$. I wish to conclude that $p|n$.

The proof follows: If $p$ is prime, then the factors of $p^{\alpha}$ are exactly given by $1, p, p^2, ..., p^{\alpha}$ (should I give any further justification for this?). In supposing that the common factor is given by $p^{j}$, then since $p|p^{j}$ and $p^{j}|n$, we have that $p|n$.

Is there a better proof for this?

Comment: Looks good at first glance to me.
I'm guessing your in a Discrete Math course, not an Abstract Algebra course.  Whether you need to justify the factors will depend on context, but probably don't need it.

Comment: You can prove it that way using unique factorization. But it's more general to use Euclid's Lemma as in the dupe, i.e. if  $p$ were coprime to $n$ then so too would be $p^n$ (being a product of coprimes). You can also invoke Euclid's lemma directly: prime $\,q\mid (n,p^n)\Rightarrow q\mid p^n\Rightarrow q\mid p\Rightarrow q=p.\ \ $

Comment: Explicitly: OP contrapositive is $\,(p,n)=1\Rightarrow (p^k,n)=1,\,$ which by Bezout is equivalent to $\!\bmod n\!:\ p^{-1}$ exists $\Rightarrow (p^k)^{-1}\,$ exists, true by $\,(p^k)^{-1}\equiv (p^{-1})^k.\,$ That's the *arithmetical* view behind the proof presented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3555162/242) in the dupe. $\ \ $

Comment: If the gcd is not $1$ , there must be a prime both dividing $n$ and $p^\alpha$. The only possible such prime is $p$ since $p^\alpha$ has only one prime factor.

Comment: @Peter That's the same as the "direct" proof in my first comment.