# $a + b$, $b^{p - 1}$ coprime when $a$, $b$ coprime for odd prime $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I was reading a proof of the theorem
$$\gcd\bigg(\frac{a^p + b^p}{a + b}, a + b\bigg) \in \{1, p\}$$
where $a$, $b$ are coprime integers and $p$ is an odd prime. Using long division, we get
$$\gcd(a + b, pb^{p - 1})$$
which equals $\gcd(a + b, p) \in \{1, p\}$ because $a + b$ and $b^{p - 1}$ are coprime.

I don't understand how that's true though. I tried using the Euclidean algorithm but still don't see how $\gcd(a + b, b^{p - 1}) = 1$.

Comment: $(a+b,b)=(a,b)=1$ so $(a+b,b^n)=1$ by iterating Euclid's Lemma, or by [coprimes (to $a+b)$ are closed under products](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3555162/242), or by the gcd Freshman's Dream etc as in the linked dupes .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\gcd(a+b,b^p)|\gcd(a+b,b)^p=1^p=1$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)

Comment: Agreed - didn’t realize it was a dupe (though I probably should have checked given the simplicity). Also, he wasn’t asking that question - he was asking for clarification on a solution.

Comment: We have *hundreds* of dupes of this. It is best not to add more (beware that continuing to answer dupes can lead to account suspension, cf. above-linked policy).